# How to create net.tcp WCF Service with permanent connections

Tags: c#, wcf

How to create net.tcp WCF Service with a large pool of client permanent connections

I need to call a lot of clients on NAT

I did it on the net sockets using a pool of permanent client sockets, but do not know how this is done on WCF

Since duplex WCF provides access to current connections but does not keep them.

How to develop a WCF service to which the client connects from behind NAT 1 once, and then throughout the day on this connections of his calls from the server.

The number of client connections more than 85000

Now It works on DuplexChannelFactory, how to call at any time, any client of 85000 without client reconnect?

Comment: Check out the bindings in the ServiceBus... there are special bindings for persistent NAT connections.

Comment: I do not have ServiceBus, and how to choose a client who I want to call?

Comment: If you have development control over the client and server, then the service bus is free and from MSFT

Comment: You can add a link to an example of implementing client-server ?

Comment: Microsoft has a ton of samples... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193022.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35374

Comment: or look at the azure version http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27421